# How to dynamically set number of swipeable tabs in Action Bar with Fragments at runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am referring this [link for swipeable tabs using fragments](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/). It worked for me, but what if I need to add the number of tabs dynamically and not pre assign the number of tabs? For instance, some of my logic gives me output at times 2 strings in anarray and at times 4 strings in an array. And according to the logic I need to set the number of tabs in action bar at runtime. How can I achieve this? Can anyone show me how to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**STEP 1:**

Define your `TabsPagerAdapter` as follows:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> list;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> list) {
        super(fm);
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

}
```

**STEP 2:**

When you determine the number of tabs at runtime, first make sure to create a `List` of the required number of `Fragment`s. You can do it using either *this*:

```
ArrayList<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
for(int i = 0; i < tabcount; i++){
    list.add(MyFragment.newInstance());
}
```

**OR** *this*:

```
ArrayList<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
list.add(new GamesFragment());
list.add(new TopRatedFragment());
list.add(new MoviesFragment());
```

**STEP 3:**

When you create an `Adapter` for the `ViewPager`, pass the `ArrayList` of `Fragment`s in the constructor of `TabsPagerAdapter`:

```
TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(fm, list);
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: What does MyFragment stands for in for loop? Is it my MainActivity Fragment or something else?

Comment: `MyFragment` is the class of the `Frament`s held by the `ViewPager` ... in the example you have linked the `Fragment`s inside the `ViewPager` are the `GamesFragment`, `TopRatedFragment` etc ... are you able to understand this ??

Comment: Well the Fragment that helds my ViewPager is MainActivity as per example which extends FragmentActivity class. and if I give MainActivity in place of MyFragment in your code it give me error under newInstance(), saying the newInstance() method is not defined for MainActivity. Could you please eleborate more as I am a newbee.

Comment: As I have said, `MyFragment` is the `Fragment` **INSIDE** the `ViewPager`, whereas `MainActivity` is the `FragmentActivity` that holds your `ViewPager` ... you are misunderstanding the two

Comment: Just create a class `MyFragment` which extends `Fragment` and put a simple test layout in it, like a `TextView` or an `ImageView`, and then first test it. After it works properly, the `MyFragment` class can be customized more :)

Comment: so even if I write any of the Fragment in the ViewPager as per example i.e GameFragment or TopRatedFragment or etc. it gives me the same error. What should I do, please eleborate it as per the example.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Adapter` make method `addTab`, something like:

```
private final ArrayList<TabInfo> tabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

public void addTab(String tabName, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
{
   TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, tabName);
   tabs.add(info);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}

... ...

static final class TabInfo
{
   private final Class<?> clss;
   private final String title;

   TabInfo(Class<?> _class, String _title)
   {
      clss = _class;
      title = _title;
   }
```

and your method `getCount`:

```
@Override
public int getCount(){
   return tabs.size();
}
```

all your fragments/tabs should be added by `addTab`:

```
mAdapter.addTab(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_name), YourFragment.class, null);
```

Comment: What does YourFragment.class stand for? does it is my MainActivity that extends FragmentActivity or something else?

Comment: Each tab corresponding one Fragment, right? so when you add one tab, naturally also add one Fragment